# Gnome/ubuntu: find window 'handler' by a point

Tags: api, ubuntu, window, gnome

I know there is a function named windowFromPoint in the API of Windows, I wonder if there is a counterpart for ubuntu/gnome? I'm not very familiar with the window manager of linux, can someone show me the right direction?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely going to be harder than you'd expect.  The library you need to work with is Xlib, not GTK (after all, your desktop could have GTK and QT windows open).  The function you'll want to call, I think, is [XQueryPointer](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XQueryPointer.html).  And I think you'll need to use GDK to get a reference to the underlying X server connection, though I'm not really familiar with either Xlib or GDK.